# Accessing PHP web service in iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, web-services

I have accessed .net webservices in iPhone,now i like to develop PHP webservice which has to be consumed by my iPhone application.

Is it possible to consume a PHP web service in iPhone,if possible can anybody suggest me a good tutorial or web reference for designing a simple web service in PHP and consuming it through a iPhone application.

Thank a lot in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's perfectly possible. The client (iPhone) doesn't care in the very least what programming language you use on the server, as long as the output (HTML, XML, JSON, whatever else you want to consume) is something the client understands.

You don't need a tutorial, it's no different from making a normal website with PHP.

Comment: Thanks deceze for making me understand.